# Realtime API for WorldPay "Capture"

Tags: api, shopify, worldpay

I'm led to believe Shopify uses a "Realtime" API to Capture the payment from WorldPay (using WorldPays API this seems to work on a deffered basis).  Reviewing the [Shopify API documentation](http://api.shopify.com/transactions.html), this gives me some of the picture but not all.

1. I can see that I've got to call "Create a new Transaction" (`POST /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.xml`). The `#{id}` I presume is the authorization id. Do I need the `#` and or `{}` brackets?
2. Is the URL purely `http://lumie.myshopify.com/admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.xml` or is
   there a shop guid `/` code that has to be passed as well?
3. I can see the response message for a success, but what about failures such as expired authorization codes. Do you have any examples of these?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `#` or `{}` symbols in the id, just the digits.

The ID in the URL is the ID of the order in Shopify that you're trying to capture payment for.  You can retrieve this from the [Orders API](http://api.shopify.com/order.html).

To call any API endpoint you need to be authenticated. We use OAuth 2.0 as our auth mechanism, and the process is described in our [Authentication Docs](http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html). Ultimately you'll get an OAuth token that you put into an `X-Shopify-Access-Token` header on each API request.

Valid values for Transaction status are `success` and `pending`. Anything else is an error.